# Reading Date from database in Ipad

Tags: sqlite, core-data, ios4, ipad, nsdateformatter

say for example I have the following piece of code with which I retrieve the date from the database

```
        DateLabel.text = [CommonHelper getDateString:objSample.startDate :@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

where

i) `objSample` is an object of my `Sample` entity

ii) `startDate` is an attribute in the `Sample` entity declared as `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * startDate;`

iii)`CommonHelper` is another file where I have the `getDateString:` function as below,

```
+ (NSString *) getDateString:  (NSDate *) date: (NSString *) format
  {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:format]; 
    NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormat release];
    return dateStr;
   }
```

Using Sqlite Database Browser, if I enter the value as "04/23/1999" to the Sample's startDate attribute , the value which is displayed in `DateLabel.text` is a totally different value and if I enter a value such as "76851234", the value which is displayed in `DateLabel.text` is "05/23/2001".

Since I am new in dealing with database, I am unable to understand why this happens... 
Would someone be able to tell me why this happens? and is there a way I can directly enter the date into the database using SQLite Database Browser so that that date is displayed?

is the format of the date I enter into the SQLite database browser a "Unix Date Format"? if so, how would I be able to convert the date into unix date format so that I know for certain what would be the exact date I would be displaying on my app...

Comment: How is this related to core data?

Comment: @ fluchpunkt.. sorry I had framed my question badly and wrongly.. I changed the question now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this is that you can't.

SQLite is "**typeless**". This means that you can store any kind of data you want in any column of any table, regardless of the declared datatype of that column. http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html

Comment: I changed my question.. I had framed my question wrong the first time.. would you be able to tell me the solution??